# Uploading App Bundle to Google Play stuck in processing

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I signed the app bundle with a generated key using the android studio developer built in tool. I also opted into google play key signing. When I upload the app bundle to the release, it says

"Google Play is generating and optimizing APKs from your Android App Bundle. This may take a few minutes, depending on the size of your app bundle."

But this goes on forever. My bundle is only around 2 MB. Is this normal?

Comment: Same here, it worked 8 hours ago, now it's broken. It's unrelated to bundles as I still sign my own APKs. It just says "processing". My apk is only 300K, it takes a fraction of a sec to upload, then it processes for 10 minutes, then it times out. Hopefully Google fixes it soon. I reported the issue using the ? / Email in the upper right.

Comment: Same here, i was tried with apk and aab, all of them are stuck in processing and error after about 5 mins.

Comment: same here, seems issue popped up today only.

Comment: same here, looks like they are having an issue

Comment: Wow.. so its just not me then! I guess Google engineers have some fixing to do.

Comment: Same here.. it's still not working until now

Comment: Please reach out to Play Console support team so this can be investigated: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contactflow

Comment: Looks like its fixed!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Publishing an apk on google play store is stuck at processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55134234/publishing-an-apk-on-google-play-store-is-stuck-at-processing)

Answer (score 5):

This happened to me and made me stuck for several hours. Finally got the solution,

**Make sure the Date and time of your computer is correct at the time of generating the signed APK or app Bundle.**

Basically it  causes the the certificate to get rejected by Google server, and due to some kind of bug on Google side, the error is not reported to user when user upload App bundles (AAB), but it report back error in case of APK upload

Comment: My aab had a modification date that was one minute later than the creation date. Rebuilding didn't work. Then I cleared the caches and changed the aab filename, and the upload worked again. I'm not sure what exactly the problem was though.

Comment: Not sure if this is the case, but the issue got resolved after rebuilding the App

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be an issue on google's side and it seems to be fixed now

Comment: Nope. Still not fixed to this day.

Answer (score 2):

For me, changing the browser from Chrome to Edge worked.

Comment: worked for me as well but instead of Edge its Safari.

Answer (score 1):

Change your internet connection. I have the same problem too, I've tried using mobile data, wifi in my home but still have the same problem. And then I'm using wifi at my campus, it's so fast and finally I can upload my app bundle without stuck at processing status.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen these same symptoms with a different cause, which is what brought me to this question, so I'm offering another potential cause and answer, for others who encounter the situation I did.

That is, I uploaded an APK and when it reached 100% it said "processing..." and stayed in that status forever.

I researched and found this answer, but in my case it was not a temporary problem. Another user mentioned that he had determined that this also happens when posting a 64-bit APK for a release before a 32-bit APK version. Posting the 32-bit APK first works, but when I post a 64-bit APK first, it sits "processing..." forever.

Comment: @Dharman That is not what I did here. This question describes a symptom where Android Studio gets stuck "processing" forever. The OP was running into one temporary cause of this problem. I came to this question looking for an answer to the same symptom. It turns out my answer was different and not temporary. If I had come here like I did yesterday and someone had answered the question as I just did, it would have been very valuable to me. I added this answer because I think it provides useful information about what can cause the symptom the question is about.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me now and it was showing "uploading" for about 15 minutes on my fibre connection, So I reloaded the page and uploaded again. It just took seconds to upload that time. So try reloading the page and trying again.